Crear archivo en Ionic, Capacitor, Android 13 en carpeta Documents
estoy intentando crear un archivo .zpl desde Ionic, Capacitor, con Angular sin exito.
Si pude escribir perfectamente, con un Android 13 en External Storage, pero esa carpeta esta ubicada dentro de la carpeta Android, la cual por seguridad esta protegida.
Lo que quiero preguntarles es, es posible crear un archivo .zpl desde Ionic, con Capacitor, con Angular y generarlo en la carpeta Documents o no me dejara y solo puedo escribir en External Storage?
Adjunto la librería utilizada para crear y escribir el archivo:
https://capacitorjs-com.translate.goog/docs/apis/filesystem?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es&_x_tr_pto=wapp
!Muchisimas gracias!

Actualmente, existen restricciones de seguridad para escribir fuera de los directorios de la aplicación, pero es posible escribir en Documents, pero lo ideal es usar FilesystemDirectory.Documents ,  puedes revisar los ejemplos de la documentación para crear un archivo dentro del directorio Documents (define directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents):
import { Plugins, FilesystemDirectory, FilesystemEncoding } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

async fileWrite() {
  try {
    const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: 'secrets/text.txt',
      data: "This is a test",
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
      encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
    })
    console.log('Escribio archivo', result);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('No pudo escribir el archivo', e);
  }
}

